# How Many Ways To Empty The Glove Box?

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

Inspired by [this glove-themed 538 Riddler Express Puzzle](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/can-you-get-the-gloves-out-of-the-box/).

### Task

You are given a positive integer `n`, and a list `A = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_k]` of `k` distinct positive integers.

Then a restricted composition is an ordered list `P = [p_1, p_2, ..., p_m]` where each `p_i` is a (not necessarily distinct) member of `A`, and `p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_m = n`.

So, if `n = 10`, and `A = [2,3,4]` then an example of a restricted composition would be `P = [3,4,3]`. Another example would be `P = [2,3,3,2]`. A third example would be `P = [3,3,4]`. But there's no restricted composition that starts `[3,3,3,...]`, because `10-(3+3+3) = 1`, which is not in `A`.

We want the total number of different restricted compositions given the inputs, as an integer.

### Inputs

A positive integer `n` and a list `A` of distinct positive integers. All reasonable input formats allowed.

### Output

The number of distinct restricted compositions.

### Terms and Conditions

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); and thus we seek the shortest submissions in bytes satisfying the constraints. Any use of the usual loopholes voids this contract.

### Test Cases

```
(5, [2, 3, 4]) => 2
(10, [2, 3, 4]) => 17
(15, [3, 5, 7]) => 8
```

Comment: Ah, a variant on the knapsack problem. [Related XKCD](https://xkcd.com/287/)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Jonathan Allan*

```python
f=lambda n,A:n>=0and(n<1)+sum(f(n-x,A)for x in A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU/H0SrPztYgMS9FI8/GUFO7uDRXI00jT7dCx1EzLb9IoUIhM0/BUfN/QVFmXolCmoapjkK0kY6CsY6CSawmF0zU0AC7MEg1UAxImcdq/gcA)

Comment: A little bit of a switcharoo can [save a byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU/H0SrPztYgMS9FI8/GUFO7uDRXI00jT7dCx1EzLb9IoUIhM0/BUfN/QVFmXolCmoapjkK0kY6CsY6CSawmF0zU0AC7MEg1UAxImcdq/gcA)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>48</s>  40 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(n)`.

```javascript
a=>g=n=>n>0?a.map(x=>t+=g(n-x),t=0)|t:!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7dNs/WLs/OwD5RLzexQKPC1q5E2zZdI0@3QlOnxNZAs6bESjHvf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RppGtJGOgrGOgkmspoaCqaamgr6@ghEXTiWGBhAlhuboaoAKTHUUzEFqoMZY/AcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>24</sup> 17 bytes

```
1#.[=1#.[:>@,{\@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1om1BhJWdg051jIPyf02u1OSMfAUjBVsFU4U0BQ0bIwVjBROoqKE5UNjQAEn8PwA)

Recursive version was too verbose in J, so I went brute force.

Take the integers in the right arg as a boxed list and the target number `n` in the left arg.

- `{\@#` - We create a series of cartesian products of the list with itself, starting with 1 (the list unchanged) and up to `n` (the list crossed with itself n times).
- `[:>@,` We flatten all of those, open them, and sum them.
- `[=` Check which sums equal `n`.  This returns a boolean list.
- `1#.` Sum it.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

Accepts `n` as the right argument and `A` as the left argument.

```apl
{⍵>0:+/⍺∘∇¨⍵-⍺⋄⍵=0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71b7QystPUf9e561DHjUUf7oRVAIV0Qt7sFyLI1qP3/30jBWMFEIU3BlAvGMjTgMlYwVTAHMU0B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>6</s>  5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṗⱮẎ§ċ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4bmX4rGu4bqOwqfEi////1syLDMsNF3/MTA)** (Very inefficient.)

#### How?

Builds all lists of lengths \$1\$ to \$n\$ made from the integers in \$A\$ and then counts how many sum to \$n\$.

```
ṗⱮẎ§ċ - Link: list of positive integers, A; positive integer, n
 Ɱ    - map across x in (implicit range [1..n]) applying:
ṗ     -   Cartesian power -> all length x lists made from values in A
  Ẏ   - tighten (to a list of lists)
   §  - sum each list
    ċ - count occurrences of (n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 23 bytes

```
{$[x>0;+/(x-y)o\:y;~x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlolusLOwFpbX6NCt1IzP8aq0rquIrb2fwhIprKuyCpNQU@hwjohP9taIyEtMTPHusK60rpIM7aWKyRaQ8HU2kjBWMFEE0jFggQMDWAChuYQAVNrYwVTBXNNawuF2P8A)

recursive

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 57 bytes

Port of the Python answer.

```
f :=method(n,A,if(n>0,A map(x,f(n-x,A))sum,if(n==0,1,0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fclLCoMwFEbhuau4w3vhF6JWhEIKWUpBQwPmQY3g7tMgQmfOzuFzsRRLT@2X/IkzBxg4y@GlYMi/Ex@o1x4wItvuT9NaoYMSkWJ5JNDqtsw9aAA9RCh9XchraCx36g7HC6vUnP5Yfg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
#o=¹ΣuṖ*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Xznf9tDOc4tLH@6cpvX//3/j/9GGOkY6xrEA)

This is so ridiculously inefficient that it struggles on [TIO](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Xznf9tDOc4tLH@6cpvX//3/j/9GGOkY6xrEA) to even run any of the given test cases: link is to a super-easy test case of n=2, a=[1,2,3] (for which [output is 4](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py3f9tDOc4tLH@6cpvX//3/j/9GGOkY6xrEA)).

Repeats and concatenates (`*`) the input list n times, and then generates all possible subsets (`uṖ` - this is the slow step!).  Then counts the number (`#`) of subsets for which the total equals n (`o=¹Σ`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/language/), <s>56</s> <s>49</s> <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

2 bytes golfed thanks to [J42161217](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67961/j42161217)

```
n_~f~a_=If[n<1,1+Sign@n,Tr[f[n-#,a]&/@a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8vvi6tLjHe1jMtOs/GUMdQOzgzPc8hTyekKBoooquskxirpu@QGBv7P6AoM6/EIS3aVKfaSMdYx6Q2lgsmZGiARQyozljHVMe8Nvb/fwA)

Initial solution:

```
Length[Join@@Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[#,∞,#2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yc1L70kI9orPzPPwSEgtSi3tAQol59XrO/gmVeSmp5aFJBYVJIJFopW1nnUMU9H2Sg2Vu1/QFFmXolDWrSpTrWRjrGOSW0sF0zI0ACLGFCdsY6pjnlt7P//AA)

Comment: nice port! [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8vvi6tLjHe1jMtOs/GUMdQOzgzPc8hTyekKBoooquskxirpu@QGBv7P6AoM6/EIS3aVKfaSMdYx6Q2lgsmZGiARQyozljHVMe8Nvb/fwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @J42161217 Thanks! That's a clever use of infix notation btw, I wouldn't have thought of using it for function definition

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMtWtnGUMdQOzgzPc9BWUfZIFpZN1NH2Si2Lrg0t64axKyNVfsfUJSZV@KQFm2qU22kY6xjUhvLBRMyNMAiBlRnrGOqY14b@/8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
⊞υ¹Ｆθ⊞υ↨Φυ№η⁻⊕ιλ¹Ｉ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy7CgIxEEV7v2LKGRjBXe22c0GwENIvW4QYSSAmmsf@/pgtLM89l2OczibpIKJacdgYBpoOr5QBvwT/7aqLxZsP1eYd59RiRcfw8LEVvEeT7dvGap/oiSEQ0d7pIZV9f866VFTpg62bSWQZTgzLyHBmuKyrHLfwAw) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 1 byte by using base conversion from 1 instead of summing a potentially empty list. Explanation:

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start our result list with the number of solutions for `n=0` which is always `1` (the empty list).

```
Ｆθ⊞υ
```

Loop `n` times, so that we calculate the results for `1..n`, appending them to the result list.

```
↨Φυ№η⁻⊕ιλ¹
```

Sum those results so far that contribute to the next total. For example, if `A` is `[2, 3, 4]`, then to calculate the result for `n=10`, we already know the results for `n=0..9`, but we only add the results for `n=6`, `n=7` and `n=8`. The sum is calculated by converting from base 1 in case the list is empty.

```
Ｉ⊟υ
```

Print the result for `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>40</s> 36 bytes

Python answer port but Ruby strict typing means I can't coerce booleans into integers.

-4 bytes from dingledooper.

```ruby
f=->n,a{n>0?a.sum{|e|f[n-e,a]}:1<<n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtNCoMwFIT3nmIWpYsSQ4wGi6g9SBFJaWwFfQ1VKUU9e/o2XQzz8zHv5fYNoavimoRdqVYXK6dlXDe3dVeKnbDNXiRlSXv4PPvB4eHmKQJI4GRR4dDKyQ/9LEfrcSzmV9sz9eCzgG0iR/dgoJEiixL1D4bNIOegGHLVOU8pyxhkWsGc1Q8)

Comment: I think you can get around the 'boolean issue' by using `1<<n` instead of `n==0?1:0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 89 bytes

Port of the Python answer.

Edit: Outgolfed by Noodle9 :/

```c
int n;f(int x,int*a){if(x<=0)return!x;int y=0,i=0;while(i++<n)y+=f(x-a[i-1],a);return y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzLDoIwEEXX8BUVY9LKYEAkLkr9EXRRXjIJVoMQIYRvx1ZcsrmTmXPnZN49y@Ytqqzu8oLE7zbH56G6zKhaonhJzexB516yEUvax8JnTdF2jdr03NBB@IDC558K64Ki68aKDa7QVU8m6AU3kIwvH2Tg08/8kKgoG23LLDK5EUHGI4RwmrhtKRHqfDWaldTZ5VflQEkjrWEr98D/A6NKF1UIEZyntXIEqSlP8xc)

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYzRCoIwFIav8ymWUWx5DM0kaM4exLyYU2tQM0zBIXt2m9SlNwf@83//J/y7ENNGKvHsywoln66UzeGRTorWeAAOGiSRqttzOtZNizWTLKBDGuxkoijRHrOYzzPpeTlwQtuq61uFhiS8roeLpmayY/TiUmEyOqs58CxHDI1HiOBkqLNSLLL33dquxu62vCkXahxbG1n4h8G/mFXFTxVBDGezBMdQzLCZvg "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>65</s></sup> 63 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [my pronoun is monicareinstate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/my-pronoun-is-monicareinstate)!!!

```c
f(n,a,l,s,i)int*a;{for(s=i=!n;i<l&n>0;)s+=f(n-a[i++],a,l);n=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBDoIwEAXvfEUl0XTtkoDYeKj1R5BDqalpgquh3ki/vZYQT3p982Zsdbc2JccJDY4Y0IOn996o2T0nHrTXG1L@PO7oUisIQudnZTovRL8IoEgHFdPDeOIwF9llQ9czzeYDshbZMariNeXZ8XJ7u1KJjkscsAX4BU39JUvHrp0ckchOfzqNRLveY/oA)

Comment: You can remove `i++` by moving the `++` to `f(n-a[i],...)`. I do not know the algorithm nor the problem itself, but if I replace `s=!n,i=0` with `i=s=!n`, I get the same answers for the test cases.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Just moved the `++` but thanks for the `i` init! If `!n` isn't `0` the `for` loop isn't going to run and `i` isn't used.  Nice one :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 52 bytes

```
$r.=1x$_."|"}{(1x$^I)=~/^($r@){1,$^I}$(?{$\++})(*F)/
```

### Usage

```
printf "2\n3\n4" | perl -p -i10 glovebox.pl
```

### Explanation

Attempts to turn the problem into a string matching one, then uses regex backtracking to do the hard work! In the example given above it ends up constructing a regex match similar to `1111111111 =~ /^(1{2}|1{3}|1{4}){1,10}$(?{$count++})(*F)/`

This will cause the regex engine to attempt each combination of the regex, using `(?{$count++})` to increase `$count` each time the engine matches the input and reaches that point in the pattern, but forcing a fail `(*F)` before the match returns to cause the engine to backtrack and start again with the next combination. `$count` ends up being the answer.

Slightly different approach, was hoping it'd end up a bit shorter though...

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
n!a|n<0=0|n<1=1|n>0=sum$(!a).(n-)<$>a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmvoaipYGWl4JlXoqBrpxANpGNBDCD9P08xsSbPxsDWAEga2hrW5NkZ2BaX5qpoKCZq6mnk6WraqNgl/s9NzMxTsFVIyedSUCgoygSao6JgqqCoEG2ko2Cso2ASiyRuaIBLAqwDKGqqo2Ae@x8A)

Quick port of the Python answer, call as `n ! a`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L€ãO˜¹¢
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

Very slow approach!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f51HTmsOL/U/PObTz0KL//w0NuKKNdBSMdRRMYgE) or [verify the first two test cases at once](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6KGV/33ObY0oPry41v/0nEPrDi36r/M/OtpURyHaSMdYxyQ2FsgyNEBwYwE) (third one times out..).

**Explanation:**

```python
L        # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input-integer]
 €       # Map over each integer in this list
  ã      #  Take the cartesian product of the second (implicit) input-list that many times
   O     # Sum each inner-most list
    ˜    # Flatten the list of lists
     ¹¢  # And count how many times the first input occurs in this list
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅœʒåP}€œ€`Ùg
```

Here a faster (but now way longer) approach using the `Åœ` builtin.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOvRyacmHV4aUPuoac3RyUAi4fDM9P//DU25oo11THXMYwE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6P/DrUcnn5oUUXx4aUDto6Y1RycDiYTDM9P/6/yPjjbVUYg20jHWMYmNBbIMDVC5IFljHVMd89jYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åœ         # Get all lists of positive integer that sum to the (implicit) input-integer
  ʒ        # Filter this list of lists by:
   å       #  Check for each value whether it's in the second (implicit) input-list
    P      #  And check if this is truthy for all of them
  }€œ      # After the filter: get the permutations of each remaining list
     €`    # Flatten one level down
       Ù   # Uniquify the list of lists
        g  # Pop and push the length for the amount of remaining lists
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: 7 bytes with your first approach: [`L€ãO˜¹¢`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f51HTmsOL/U/PObTz0KL//w0NuKKNdBSMdRRMYgE)

Comment: @ovs Oh, that's indeed a lot better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 35 bytes

*port of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203346/98541) Python answer*

```julia
f(n,A)=n>=0&&+(n<1,f.(n.-A,[A])...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NCsIwEIXX5hSPIpLgGFp/qAtT6DlKF6IJpJQotkIPIq48nRepTVo34oNh4L1v3lT32h6Tru8Nd5QL5TIVLxZL7g4JGcmdXOVU5KWQUoq@1U3bQKFgGMR3hGJN2BC2pYDKsKYxSOLfJEm/kT8a/GGlY7QnVjJmLjdwS5WAdQh/Am8NDLf@OZRCFTyv6826tnY8er8eiAjWN02kCJSuG/0Pf/7ihGjGdXfVp1afMa9ENBW4Mxum/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 55 bytes

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
g=function(t,l,u=t-l)sum(!u,unlist(sapply(u[u>0],g,l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfnpNflpqUX2H7P902rTQvuSQzP0@jRCdHp9S2RDdHs7g0V0OxVKc0LyezuESjOLGgIKdSozS61M4gViddJ0dTUxNugoapTrKGkY6xjommpoKyghEXXMLQAEXG0BxJCqTJWMdUxxwsZfEfAA)

Recursively removes each element from the glove box, and calls itself with the new total if there's anything left.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfnpNflpqUX2H7P902rTQvuSQzP0@jRCdHp9S2RDdHs7g0V0OxVKc0LyezuESjOLGgIKdSozS61M4gViddJ0dTUxNugoapTrKGkY6xjommpoKyghEXXMLQAEXG0BxJCqTJWMdUxxwsZfEfAA)?

Comment: @Giuseppe - Yes!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 54 bytes

```
Tr[Length/@Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[#,All,#2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6Qo2ic1L70kQ98hILUot7QEKJOfV6zv4JlXkpqeWhSQWFSSCRaKVtZxzMnRUTaKjVX7H1CUmVei4JAebapTbaRjrGNSG8sFFzM0wCYIVGmsY6pjXhv7/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```
f: func[x y][case[x = 0[1]x < 0[0]on[sum collect[foreach a y[keep f x - a y]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCoMwEETvfsXgXdDaUihtP6LXZQ8xbmhpNBIV9OvTTaGHzmXmMcNE6dNDeuLkLnDraGnDzmTNLJpuqKnhDVf1msNI8zrABu/FLuRCFGOfMNjpLTLBYUOVkbPSryeDjqlA1gl0QIsjf7Gp/1HbVidnLpgwxde4gPRvCL5Hh7K6l06xA4PTBw)

The same recursive approach almost everyone is using, much longer though.

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), <s>74</s> 64 bytes

```lisp
(λ(x y)(if(< x 1)(+(sgn x)1)(apply +(map(λ(a)(f(- x a)y))y))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYwxDsIwFEN3TmGJAX9VSC0FsfQyXzSpIkIUtQzJ2bgDVwoJIwOSB1vP9qq3u3mWvdewYP2GHWdjXTCwhe8XE7LQWU5IGIQdtyUgSbUao8/o@NDYiiq0PNaWSpYmkSL1zG3Ra/YBtLjgwBNGnCv8QUP/h7XdWNfXdvoB)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 36 bytes

```
Tr[Multinomial@@@FrobeniusSolve@##]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6Qo2rc0pyQzLz83MzHHwcHBrSg/KTUvs7Q4OD@nLNVBWTlW7X9AUWZeSbSyrl2agwOQXxecnJhXV81VXW2kY6xjUqtjWquD4BgagHnGOqY65kCeaS1X7X8A)